# Relationship between linearity and vanishing gradient

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

Suppose we have the following equations defined as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
 y_i=\sum_j{w_{ij}x_j} ,\\
 w_{ij}^{'}=x_{i}^{T}x_j ,\\
 w_{ij}=\frac{e^{w_{ij}^{'}}}{\sum_j{e^{w_{ij}^{'}}}}
\end{align}
$$
where $T$ is the transpose operation, and $w_{ij}$ is defined as the $SoftMax$ function.

In a vector form we can rearrange the equations above as follows:
$$
\begin{align}
 Y=WX^T, \\
 W=SoftMax(XX^T)
\end{align}
$$

**Question**: Since $Y$ is defined as multiplication, it's purely linear and thus is **non-vanishing** gradient, which means the gradient will be of a linear transformation. While $W=SoftMax(XX^T)$ is non-linear and thus can cause **vanishing gradients**. May I know please what is the relationship between linearity/non-linearity and vanishing/non-vanishing gradient?